# Figuring a CRC to edit a PS1 save file

Tags: crc, game-hacking, checksum

So I've set myself the goal of editing Crash Bash saves for the PS1.
I'm using RetroArch + PCSX, so I'm editing memory card .srm files binary contents directly.

Uploaded a zip with some save games, in case you want to look at them:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZgQGt4MmSoduK5lWjAT1osa1hBEbsEE/view?usp=drive_link

After editing file contents, the game ignores the save. Through trial and error, I've seen that I can't modify anything inside the range [0x2200, 0x2850), so that must be CRC-checked.

Anything before 0x2200 (e.g. file name, icons) is defined in the specs for the memory card file format in here:
https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/PS1_Savedata

The files end up with what looks to be a 32-bit CRC hash.
0x2850: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E3 B6 0C E7

Weirdly enough, the hash is at 0x285C, but the hash is not covering the gap between (0x2850, 0x285C), so I can edit those bits and the game recognizes and loads the save just fine.
I think it's safe to say that the game data is in the [0x2200, 0x2860) range and that the game is the one (i.e. not the system) running the CRC-check over [0x2200, 0x2850).

I've tried copying the hex values of the save into https://crccalc.com/ to see if any of the values would match, but no luck.

I've also tried using https://reveng.sourceforge.io/, https://crc-reveng.septs.app/ with options:
-w 32 -l -s

So that:

- -w: Assuming that the hash is 32 bit
- -l: I think that PSX is little-endian, so I assume that this CRC should also be little endian
- -s: search mode from reveng

Since reveng seems to work better with more samples, I've been doing some additional saves, so I have 6 sample files.

But that returns no results. Judging the usages I've seen (https://hackaday.com/2019/06/27/reverse-engineering-cyclic-redundancy-codes/), I think it should be fine with 6 saves, but all use cases I've seen have always been running over smaller data, so who knows.

So I'm running a bit out of ideas here. Let me know if you have any recommendations.

Comment: Note: This question also appears at the ROMHacking.net forum thread [Figuring a CRC to edit a PS1 save file](https://www.romhacking.net/forum/index.php?topic=37808.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I also posted this answer at the following ROMHacking.net forum post: [Re: Figuring a CRC to edit a PS1 save file](https://www.romhacking.net/forum/index.php?topic=37808.msg449648#msg449648)*

It looks like the "hash" function is just a simple 32-bit sum: In the files you provided, if you treat each group of 4 bytes in the range [0x2200, 0x2850) as a little-endian unsigned integer and sum them all up (modulo 2<sup>32</sup>), the sum will match the 4-byte little-endian unsigned value at 0x285C.